# apt-get upgrade "Errors were encountered while processing" after installing espeakup package

Tags: debian, apt, kali-linux

**Good evening.**

I have Kali Linux and I've been using for a pretty long time, but few days ago I faced a problem while trying to do `apt-get upgrade` and exactly the problem is attached to updating ' espeakup '.

P.S. I'm sure that the problem isn't in Kali, it's about my poor knowledges about Linux, but we are not talking about it now :) Thanks.

So, when I try to do `apt-get upgrade` it gives me back this:

```
Setting up espeakup (1:0.80-5+b3) ...
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
Job for espeakup.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl  status espeakup.service" and "journalctl  -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript espeakup, action "start" failed.
● espeakup.service - Software speech output for Speakup
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/espeakup.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2017-08-13 17:47:05 EEST; 30ms ago
   Docs: man:espeakup(8)
   Process: 1634 ExecStart=/usr/bin/espeakup -V ${VOICE} (code=exited, status=2)

Aug 13 17:47:05 kali-Ansi17 systemd[1]: espeakup.service: Unit entered faile…te.
Aug 13 17:47:05 kali-Ansi17 systemd[1]: espeakup.service: Failed with result…e'.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
dpkg: error processing package espeakup (--configure):
   subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
   espeakup
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**Next step**

It says that few lines were ellipsized, that's why I typed `systemctl -l status espeakup.service` and here is what I've got:

```
● espeakup.service - Software speech output for Speakup
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/espeakup.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2017-08-13 17:47:06 EEST; 11min ago
     Docs: man:espeakup(8)
   Process: 1682 ExecStart=/usr/bin/espeakup -V ${VOICE} (code=exited, status=2)

Aug 13 17:47:06 kali-Ansi17 systemd[1]: espeakup.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 13 17:47:06 kali-Ansi17 systemd[1]: espeakup.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 13 17:47:06 kali-Ansi17 systemd[1]: espeakup.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 13 17:47:06 kali-Ansi17 systemd[1]: Stopped Software speech output for Speakup.
Aug 13 17:47:06 kali-Ansi17 systemd[1]: espeakup.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 13 17:47:06 kali-Ansi17 systemd[1]: Failed to start Software speech output for Speakup.
Aug 13 17:47:06 kali-Ansi17 systemd[1]: espeakup.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 13 17:47:06 kali-Ansi17 systemd[1]: espeakup.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Literally, that's all I've got. I've tried to find solutions online, but I haven't succeed. And also, there was an error saying:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock – open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/cache/apt/archives/
```

and I've solved it by finishing these steps: `ps -ef | grep apt-get` then `kill -9 processnumber` and same for `ps -ef | grep dpkg` -> `kill -9 processnumber`.

By the way, I've never faced ' espeakup ' and don't even know what it stands for. So please, help me, I'm tired from receiving this error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**espeak** is a software speech synthesizer for English, and some other languages.

If you think you do not need this package, blacklist it. It seems to be disrupting your `apt-get upgrade`.

```
echo "espeak hold" | dpkg --set-selections
apt-get update  && apt-get upgrade -y
```

Comment: I've done it, but still, it gives me same error while upgrading. Also I've done `echo "espeakup hold" | dpkg --set-selections` and then I did an upgrade, but now it gives me back:

      W: APT had planned for dpkg to do more than it reported back (0 vs 4).
      Affected packages: espeakup:amd64

Comment: Did it upgrade other packages? And then get stuck on this at the end of the upgrade? Or this error was thrown at the beginning

Comment: Seems like it has updated everything else and at the end throws this

Comment: Yes that means the problem is solved. It shows this at the end because that package is disabled, and `dpkg` is warning you of that. Accept this answer so it can be useful for other people.

Answer (score 0):

The package `espeakup` is buggy see `apt-listbugs espeakup` (debian and kali-linux)

From Debian Stretch:

```
#apt-listbugs list espeakup

Retrieving bug reports... Done
Parsing Found/Fixed information... Done
grave bugs of espeakup (-> ) <Outstanding>
 b1 - #913453 - espeakup fails install and ends in broken state (Fixed: espeakup/1:0.80-11)
grave bugs of espeakup (-> ) <Resolved in some Version>
 b2 - #911120 - espeakup: Does not fully install (Fixed: 1:0.80-11)
Summary:
 espeakup(2 bugs)
```

To solve the problem edit :

```
nano /lib/systemd/system/espeakup.service
```

Change :

```
ExecStart=sh -c 'modprobe speakup_soft && /usr/bin/espeakup -V ${VOICE}'
```

To :

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'modprobe speakup_soft && /usr/bin/espeakup -V ${VOICE}'
```

Then set the default voice under `/etc/default/espeakup` for example:

```
VOICE=fr
```

Then run the following commands:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start espeakup
```

Check the status:

```
systemctl status espeakup
```

[See Debian Bug report logs - #913453 Date: Sun, 11 Nov 2018 06:45:01 UTC](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=913453)